# Stuck in this tutorial about functions as values

Tags: javascript

I'm following this lesson: http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/lesson?id=1040

These are the instructions:

> Define a function named applyTest that takes two arguments, a function
>   f and an input x. Your function should return a list that contains x,
>   the function f on the input x, and the function f on the input 0.

This is what I've done so far:

```
var f = function (x) {
    return x + 2;
};

var g = function (x) {
    return x * 3;
};

var applyTest = function (f, x) {
    return [x, f(2), f(0)];
};
```

and this is what JSLint is saying:

```
PASSED No JSLint errors
PASSED applyTest is a function
PASSED applyTest(f, 1)[0] === 1
FAILED applyTest(f, 1)[1] === 3 (4 !== 3)
PASSED applyTest(f, 1)[2] === 2
PASSED applyTest(f, 2).compareArrays([2, 4, 2])
FAILED applyTest(g, 3).compareArrays([3, 9, 0])
```

How do I correct that code in order to pass the lesson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bad

```
var applyTest = function (f, x) {
    return [x, f(2), f(0)];
};
```

good

```
var applyTest = function (f, x) {
    return [x, f(x), f(0)];
};
```

Comment: Damn I just made that modification. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

> Your function should return a list that contains `x`, **the function `f` on the input `x`**, and the function `f` on the input `0`.

So, `f(2)` should be `f(x)`:

```
var applyTest = function (f, x) {
    return [x, f(x), f(0)];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the requirement was to return a list of `[x, f(x), f(0)]` so change the `f(2)` to `f(x)`

Answer (score 0):

the second item on the array is wrong

> the function f on the input x

```
var applyTest = function (f, x) {
    return [x, f(x), f(0)];
};
```